# Why does the background of the CardView's rounded corners show?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to display an Image in a `CardView` using an `ImageView` as its child.

I created a layout like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.cardview.widget.CardView"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/some_image" />
</merge>
```

I expected it to show my image but its corners to be removed respectively. I didn't set any border, so the sides of the `CardView`/`merge` don't show any. However, the rounded corners of the `CardView` do show some sort of border or maybe remnants of it's background color or something:

[image: CardView Corner]

As you can see, the corner shows some grey pixels and then the straight parts of the card view don't (there might be some color difference between the black of the background and the black of the inside image but you can ignore that, it really just happens at the corners).

I played with a few things like `app:cardElevation`, suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42363217/4687402) or `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap` in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42363259/4687402) under the same question and it didn't change.

Most of the questions and posts I've found regarding the `CardView`'s corners have more to do with the actual border of the `CardView`, which is not the case for me. The Image gets cropped respective to the rounded corners, but those gray lines appear.

This happens with `ImageView` or if I just put a `View` in its stead and color its background to a similar color. If I use a bright color, this doesn't seem to happen. And I don't mean it's less noticeable, but it actually doesn't happen:

[image]

I suspected that the original background of the `CardView` might somehow be responsible for this, so I set `setCardBackgroundColor` to the same value as the background and it actually removed the ugly gray corners. So it looks to me, even though my `ImageView` fills the parent `CardView` completely, the corners somehow shine through.

So I have my answer as to how to avoid those ugly gray lines, but I don't understand how this happens and whether this is the `right way` to go about this or whether it's just a bug I found a workaround for. Have I done something wrong?

I'm using a Pixel 4a.

Comment: try setting the ``adjustViewBounds="true"`` to the image and try.

Comment: @OMiShah This doesn't work and as I said, the same effect occurs, when I simply use a View. Which doesn't have `adjustViewBounds`.